# How to use includes in typescript and Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have the following code that uses VueJS 3, Typescript to do a small function that distinguishes isAdmin to display the list menu. Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <aside
      class="z-20 flex-shrink-0 hidden w-64 overflow-y-auto bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:block h-full border-r border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
      <div class="py-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
        <router-link  class="ml-6 text-lg font-bold text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200" to="/">
          Company
        </router-link>
        <ul class="mt-12">
          <li   class="relative px-6 py-1" v-for="page in pages" :key="page.name" >
            <router-link exact-active-class="bg-purple-400 text-white" 
            v-if="page.role.includes(isAdmin)" //ERROR
              class="inline-flex items-center w-full text-sm font-semibold transition duration-200 ease-in hover:bg-purple-500 hover:text-white  py-2 px-2 rounded-lg "
              :to="`/${page.to}`">
              <component :is="page.icon" class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
              <span  class="ml-4">{{ page.name }}</span>            
            </router-link>           
          </li>        
        </ul>       
      </div>
    </aside>

  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed, watch } from "vue";
import { HomeIcon, AdjustmentsIcon, FolderOpenIcon , CursorClickIcon, ClipboardListIcon, DuplicateIcon, MenuIcon, ChartPieIcon, CollectionIcon, FolderIcon  } from "@heroicons/vue/outline";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
const showByRole = ref<boolean>(false)
const isPagesMenuOpen = ref(false);
const active = ref<boolean>(false);
const isAdmin = ref<number>()

const route = useRoute()

const checkpath = computed(() =>{
  return route.name
})

watch(checkpath, ()=>{
  if(checkpath.value == 'aws3detail'){
  active.value = true
}
})
const pages = [
  {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    icon: HomeIcon,
    to: '',
    role: [0,1]
  },

  {
    name: 'Quản lý người dùng',
    icon: MenuIcon,
    to: 'user',
    role: [1]
  },

  {
    name: 'Quản lý File',
    icon: FolderIcon ,
    to: 'files',
    role: [0,1]
  },
  {
    name: 'AWS 3 STORAGE',
    icon: FolderOpenIcon ,
    to: 'aws3',
    role: [1]
  },
  {
    name: 'Login',
    icon: CollectionIcon,
    to: 'login',
    role: 'admin'
  },
  {
    name: 'Config',
    icon: AdjustmentsIcon,
    to: 'config',
    role: [1]
  }
]
const checkUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')||'{}')
console.log("checkUser", checkUser.is_admin)
//v-if= isAdmin == item.role.includes(checkUser.is_admin)
 isAdmin.value = checkUser.is_admin
</script>
```

*And it gives error: Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)*

When I view the properties of the includes function it shows the following: method) includes(arg0: never, arg1: number | undefined): boolean

Is there any solution for me? Thanks

Comment: You need to await the result of the asynchronous `JSON.parse()` function.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution :**

- Put your "**isAdmin.value**" assignement in "**OnBeforeMount**" for a best practice reason.
- Add a type for "**checkUser**" like in the code below

Give a feedback, feel free to ask everything in comment and put your post in *solved* status if the code below solves your problem.

```html
<script setup lang=ts>
...
onBeforeMount(() => {
  const checkUser: {is_admin?: number} = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')||'{}');
  isAdmin.value = checkUser.is_admin;
});
...
</script>
```